# Are the twin primes the only positive double zeros of this real function?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, gamma-function

[Agno's answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/122582/is-there-a-connection-between-the-closed-forms-of-these-two-infinite-products)
was extremely helpful.

For $x \in \mathbb{R}, x \ge 1$ define
$$ f(x) = \sin\frac{\pi(\Gamma(x)+1)}{\lfloor x \rfloor}$$

By Wilson's theorem the positive integer zeros of $f(x)$ are exactly
the primes and the positive real zeros are when $\Gamma(x)+1$
is an integer multiple of $\lfloor x \rfloor$.

One can replace $\lfloor x \rfloor$ by $x - \frac{i \, \log\left(-e^{\left(-2 i \, \pi x\right)}\right)}{2 \, \pi} - \frac{1}{2}$ or 
$x + \frac{\arctan\left(\cot\left(\pi x\right)\right)}{\pi} - \frac{1}{2}$.

Consider
$$ t(x) = f(x) f(x+2) $$

Double positive integer zeros of $t(x)$ appear to be the smaller
twin of twin primes, though the derivative of floor at integers complicate things.

> Q1 Is it true that the smaller twin is a double zero of $t(x)$ (possibly
>    with some relaxations of the definition)?
>
> Q2 Does $t(x)$ have positive double real zeros which are not integers?

This might happen when $\Gamma(x)+1$
is an integer multiple of $\lfloor x \rfloor$,

$\Gamma(x+2)+1$
is an integer multiple of $\lfloor x + 2\rfloor$
and by the functional equation $ x (x + 1) \in \mathbb{Q}$,
i.e. $\Gamma$ must be integer at algebraic numbers which are not
integers.

This approach might be extended to multiple zeros of prime
tuples or both $x,x^2+1$ are primes.

**Added** A plot suggest counterexamples might exist,
though couldn't find a counterexample so far neither
by root finding nor by inverting gamma (modulo errors).

[image]

**Added 2014-09-14**

Such real function exists via sum of squares.

Let $P(x)=\sin^2{(\pi  x)} + \sin^2{( \pi(\Gamma(x)+1) / x)}$

$P(x)$ vanishes exactly at the primes for real $x$ and is
nonnegative.

So $TP(x) = P(x) + P(x+2)$ vanishes exactly at the smaller twin.

$P(x)$ has complex zeros.

Comment: Added a question if the twins are really double zeros because the derivative of floor at integers complicates things.