# Getting rid of complex zeros of function with zeros the primes?

Tags: nt.number-theory, real-analysis, prime-numbers

From our [Note: simple real function with zeros greater than one the primes](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/367520640_Note_simple_real_function_with_zeros_greater_than_one_the_primes)

> simple real function with zeros greater than one the primes:
> $j_1(x)=(\sin(\pi x))^2+(\sin(\pi \frac{\Gamma(x)+1}{x}))^2$.
> For $x>0$ the function is continuous.

$j_1$ has complex zeros for $\Re(x)>1$.

> Q1 Can we remove the complex zeros while keeping the
> primes as zeros? Preferably we want to keep continuity.

Trying one approach. Define $f_1(x)=\sin(\pi x)$
and $f_2(x)=\sin(\pi \frac{\Gamma(x)+1}{x})$

We have $j_1(x)=f_1(x)^2+f_2(x)^2$.
The complex zeros of $j_1$ which are not integers
are $f_1(\rho)=\pm i \cdot f_2(\rho)$.

Assume $s$ is complex number, not an integer and $\Re(s)>1$.

Let $g(s)$ be some complex function, possibly constant.

Define $j_2(s,g(s))=g(s) f_1(s)^2 + f_2(s)^2$.

$j_2$ keeps the zeros at primes and introduces zeros

$$\sqrt{g(\rho)}=\frac{f_2(\rho)}{f_1(\rho)} \qquad (1)$$

If (1) doesn't have solution, we are done.
If it has solutions for all $g$, then $\frac{f_2(\rho)}{f_1(\rho)}$
will be very close to surjective.

Another approach might be to take $F(f_1,f_2)=0$.

Observe that we allow zeros with $\Re(s) \le 1$.

Working numerically is very hard and introduces significant
errors even for $s=41$.

Plot over the reals:

[image: plot over the reals]

Here is X-Ray,$\Re(j_1(z))=0$ is plotted red and $\Im(j_1(z))=0$
is plotted blue. The intersections of the curves are zeros.

[image: Xray]

Closely related to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/432682/is-there-real-or-complex-analytic-function-whose-positive-real-zeros-are-the-pri).

Comment: What is the question?  This seems something like an advertisement of an existing paper and an outline of a future research program rather than a question with a single, well defined answer.

Comment: @LSpice The question is the quoted stuff after `Q1`. Positive answer might not exists, but is possible to exist and it will be well defined. Negative well defined answer might exist too. I disagree that quoting paper is `advertisement`, it is common practice to cite and this save space.